# Default byte value when creating file by Filechannel#map()

Tags: java, mmap

What is the default byte value of file content, when creating a file by `Filechannel#map()`?

Is it 0 for each byte, or a undefined behavior?

A code snippet is as follows:

```
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    FileChannel fileChannel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
    MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1024 * 4);
    mappedByteBuffer.putInt(1);
    mappedByteBuffer.force();
```

After running this program, I checked the file and found that each byte is **0** except the 4-th byte.
Is it a feature or undefined behavior?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your quick reply. I have read the documentation before asking this question and found the part about "unspecified behavior". However I tried many times, and the content of file was always 0. Therefore, I'm confused and ask for help :)

Comment: "Unspecified" does not mean random or arbitrary. In this case, it means that it depends on the **operating system** *(says so right there in the [quoted text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62462680/5221149))*. For a particular OS, the result is likely always the same, e.g. zero-filled on one OS, and maybe initialized ("random") on a different OS.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map-java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode-long-long-):

> Many of the details of memory-mapped files are inherently dependent upon the underlying operating system and are therefore unspecified. **The behavior of this method when the requested region is not completely contained within this channel's file is *unspecified*.** Whether changes made to the content or size of the underlying file, by this program or another, are propagated to the buffer is unspecified. The rate at which changes to the buffer are propagated to the file is unspecified.